# Why does write() print before printf() in output redirection?

Tags: c

So I know `printf()` is higher level than `write()` and ends up using `write()`. `Printf()` is buffered and `write()` makes system calls.

Example 1, if I were to run a program with `printf()` before `write()` then it would output the value of `printf()` before the value of `write()`.

Example 2, if I were to run the same program and have it go through output redirection into a file, the value of `write()` outputs before `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This is a printf test\n");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is a write test\n", 21);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what is happening here. In example 1, is the program waiting for `printf()`s output before running `write()`? In example 2, is the program redirecting the first output that is ready? And because `write()` is lower level, and does not need to buffer like `printf()` then it is printed first?

Comment: Look up [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) and the meanings of `_IONBF`, `_IOLBF` and `_IOFBF`.  When the output goes to the terminal, you get `_IOLBF` behaviour; when the output goes to a file, you get `_IOFBF` behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answered your own question.

`printf` is buffered and `write` is not.

For output to a terminal, the C stdio system has a feature that it flushes the buffers whenever it sees a newline `'\n'`. For more about stdio buffering look at the documentation for `setvbuf`.

But when output is to a file to increase speed the stdio system does not flush the buffer. That is why `write` output appears first.

Here is some of the `strace` output from running on my Linux system:

> fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
>   mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7880b41000
>   write(1, "This is a printf test\n", 22) = 22
>   write(1, "This is a write test\n\0", 22) = 22

The `fstat` is where the stdio system detects the type of output file descriptor 1 is connected to. I believe it looks at `st_mode` and sees that it is a character device. A disk file would be a block device. The `mmap` is the memory allocation for the stdio buffer, which is 4K. Then the output is written.

Comment: I feel unclear. Matteo's answer says `usually the buffering done by libc is disabled (or a flush is forced at every carriage return)`. However, your answer says `the C stdio system has a feature that it flushes the buffers whenever it sees a newline '\n'.` printf always goes into the buffer, correct? It is just whether it gets flushed or not at carriage return?

Comment: In the example for the output redirection, is this a memory allocation thing? meaning that while the system is waiting for `printf`, it runs write first right? For the regular program run, is the C checking for carriage returns before running the next command? I understand the behavior for the output, but how does it works in depth. I hope I was able to convey what I am trying to ask and understand.

Comment: @Doug: I believe most implementations separate the output and the buffer handling. So `printf` knows nothing about the buffering. It calls internal functions that write to the buffer. Then if it is in line-buffer mode those functions check the buffer for a newline. If they find one, that line is sent to the system with `write`. If it is in fully-buffered mode it only checks for a full buffer, not newlines.

Comment: @Doug: It is not a memory allocation thing. Nothing is being waited for, exactly. What happens in fully buffered mode is that the printf output is written into the buffer. Then write is called and the write output is immediately written. Then the program exits. During exit, the buffer is flushed and written out.

Comment: Thanks! That makes more sense, this means the buffer is a stack right (LIFO)?

Comment: @Doug: Not a stack. A stack would make it output in reverse order. The output buffer is FIFO. First In, First Out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8327/discussion-between-doug-and-zan-lynx)

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with output buffering done by the C standard library.  In the first case, since you are writing on the terminal, the buffering done by libc is line-oriented  (a flush is forced at every carriage return), to show immediately on screen the text, privileging interactivity over performance (which shouldn't be an issue, since terminals aren't expected to be the target for loads of text). Because of this, the `printf` output is written immediately with some `write` call, which happens before the next one you make explicitly.

In the second case, libc detects that you're writing on a file, so, to enhance the performance, it enables buffering; because of this, *usually* the first `printf` won't immediately be committed, and your `write` will happen before libc actually flushes the buffer.

<s>Again, this is what *usually* happens. I don't think this kind of behavior is mandated by any standard</s> (***edit:*** actually, this is mandated by C99, see @Jonathan's comment) (and in the second example, even with buffering enabled, the library may decide to do a flush anyway, e.g. if the buffer gets filled by your `printf`).

Comment: The behaviour is mandated by the standard.  In C99, §7.19.3, ¶3 _When a stream is fully buffered,
characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
a buffer is filled. When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be
transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
encountered._ and ¶7 _As initially
opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
to an interactive device._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: uh, good to know, I didn't found that because I was looking for "terminal" instead of "interactive device". I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Internally `printf` will use `write` when its buffer is full. It may also do a write before the buffer is full if it detects it is writing to an interactive output such as stdout that hasn't been redirected.